# How to avoid jquery conflict between two modules in joomla?

Tags: jquery, joomla1.5

I have to use `mod_lof` `articleslideshow` and `ccnewsletter` in a joomla site. Now i am suffering from js conflict of these modules. I tried `noConflict js` to avoid this but does not work.

```
$ is not a function
 $('gototop').setStyle('opacity','0');
index....sletter (line 109)
$ is not a function
 var css=this.select(property,to);retur...parsed[p]=this.css[p].parse(to[p]);}
mootools.js (line 60)
$ is not a function
 var css=this.select(property,to);retur...parsed[p]=this.css[p].parse(to[p]);}
mootools.js (line 60)
$ is not a function
 var css=this.select(property,to);retur...parsed[p]=this.css[p].parse(to[p]);}
mootools.js (line 60)
$ is not a function
 var css=this.select(property,to);retur...parsed[p]=this.css[p].parse(to[p]);}
mootools.js (line 60)
$ is not a function
var css=this.select(property,to);retur...parsed[p]=this.css[p].parse(to[p]);
```

Please provide me some solution.

Comment: What code is failing. Can you post it.

Comment: These error message is shown $ is not a function
[Break On This Error] var _lofmain = $('lofass44');
index....sletter (line 207)
$ is not a function
[Break On This Error] el=$(el);return(!props||!el)?el:el.set...ById(el);type=(el)?'element':false;}

Comment: Can you edit your original post to contain this information. Also, what module exactly is it failing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing these are plugins. can you check the plugin source. They should have the following convention wrapping them:

```
(function($){
    //plugin code
})(jQuery)
```

This avoids any conflict my passing the `jQuery` object to the plugin as the parameter `$` that you see.

If this isn't present then there is a danger of conflict.

If its in your source code, using `jQuery` instead of `$` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've always just used the SC jquery plugin, it has a setting that nativity enables no conflict mode.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/scripts/7230?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czo4OiJzY2pxdWVyeSI7fQ%3D%3D